# How to get the week of the year in some cultures?

Tags: .net, calendar, gregorian-calendar, persian

I want to get the week of a year (in current culture), so I do:

```
var week = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar
           .GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay,
                          DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.FirstDayOfWeek);
```

When current culture is `fa-IR` (Persian) the calendar is `GregorianCalendar` and `week` value is 24 (in Persian we are in the 13th week)

but if I test it with PersianCalendar as below:

```
 var calendar = new PersianCalendar();
 var week = calendar
           .GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay,
                          DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.FirstDayOfWeek);
```

it gives a true answer (13).

I checked that culture's calendar is Persian:

```
var persianCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
                       .Where(x => x.Calendar is PersianCalendar).ToList();
```

but there is no culture.

but I need this culture because I think is not good to check if calendar is Gregorian then use Persian, if you have better idea or know anything about this please let me know it.

(As I know Gregorian calendar is old, and if I'm not wrong what happened above (with Gregorian ) is wrong. it should be similar to Persian calendar.)

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon, I don't know why you removed C# tag from this question, may be in other languages there is no such a problem, also persian calendar is for c# (I know gerigorian was available in c++ at first but currently I speak about c#).

Comment: read my revision comments please. C# 3.5 does not exist (you created that tag by mistake), and the question is not related to the C# language, but to the .NET framework, so I added that tag now.

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon, sorry u are right.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/PersianCulture.aspx

In summary, it's a limitation of the .NET framework, but a workaround is possible with reflection.

Comment: That's good, but it doesn't reduce my `if then else` problem, I can't change default calendar (because of side effects on other teams) but I can change it locally but in this case `if then else` exists.